# QGIS 3: Customize Data Source Manager Toolbar

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, toolbar, qgis-customization

I have noticed that QGis version 3.2.1 does not have the "Add vector layer" button 
[image]

on the Data Source Manager toolbar:

[image]

so each time I want to add a vector layer I need to go to Layer --> Add layer --> Add vector layer, which opens the Data Manager; or use the shortcut Ctrl+Shift+V.

Is there a way to customize the Data Source manager toolbar and add the "Add vector layer" button?

Comment: It does feel like the GUI change added another click in order to import a layer. The idea may have been to tidy up the interface, but I kind of enjoyed the previous layout. Curious to know if the older button layout is intact as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That button already exists in the **Manage Layers Toolbar**:

[image: Manage Layers Toolbar]

---

If you wanted, you could move this toolbar next to Data Source Manager toolbar for personal convenience.

Comment: Indeed, the Manage Layers Toolbar is what I needed. For some reason, this Toolbar was not active when I have asked the question. I have now activated it (right-click on any other toolbar, then on Manage Layers Toolbar). Thanks Joseph!

Comment: @MarcoAndrello - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)